# How to automatically read new data from a ListBox?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I'm trying to get all the data from a column in the database. I found how to read the data from a specific column, but it shows only the first value.

Here's some of my code. Any idea how to read and show the rest data from the column?

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    //Connect database
    String connectionstring;
    SqlConnection connection;
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Connect database
        connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Internet_Recovery.Properties.Settings.customerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))

        //Select ip values from IP_table
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Ip FROM IP_table  ", connection))
        {
            DataTable iptable = new DataTable();
            //Read ip value and add it in the listbox1
            adapter.Fill(iptable);
            listBox1.DataSource = iptable;
            listBox1.ValueMember = "Ip";
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Id";
            String num;
            num = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: what's automatically read mean?

Comment: I think you might want to explain what you want a little better, not really sure what you're looking for

Comment: Your data doesn't have and `Id` field which you're trying to bind the `DisplayMember` to. Change your query to `SELECT Id, Ip FROM IP_table`.

Comment: I, too, am not sure what your struggling with. I copied this code into a new winforms app, added the missing closing curly braces, gave it a connection to my database and selected a single column from a table. It worked exactly as expected.

Comment: @JohnKraft *It worked exactly as expected*, no it doesn't. It's missing the `Id` but you don't see it visually, so you think it works as expected. See my comment above. Apart from that, I agree with you that it works as expected :).

Comment: Your code should display all data from the `Ip` column. When you say *show the rest data from the column*, do you mean the data from the **OTHER** columns?

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree. The wording of the question is sub-optimal. After re-reading, the op seems to be using the term column when they meant row.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
String num;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Ip FROM IP_table", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();                          
        adapter.Fill(data);

        listBox1.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Ip";
    }
}

num = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your data doesn't have and `Id` field which you're trying to bind the `DisplayMember` to. Change your query to

```
SELECT Id, Ip FROM IP_table
```

Also you seem to be swapping the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. They should be:

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Ip";
```

This works and displays all data from the `Ip` column in the list. It seems that you want to display the data from the other columns too. The `ListBox` control is not the best for that and you should consider using a `GridView` control instead. However, sometimes we don't care to display the data in grid format and all we care about is displaying it as a concatenated string in each item (e.g. `firstname + " " lastname`). If that's your case, you can either concatenate the columns in the query or in the code. Let's say you have the following columns in your table:

- Id (e.g. 1)
- Ip (e.g. 111.111.111)
- Location (e.g. Virginia)
- Provider (e.g. AT&T)

And let's assume you want to display them like this `111.111.111 AT&T (Virginia)`, then you can change your query to:

```
SELECT Id, Ip + ' ' + Provider + ' (' + Location + ')' AS Description FROM IP_table
```

And now you can change your binding properties to:

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
```